# What does the group_keys argument to pandas.groupby actually do?

Tags: python, pandas

In [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), there is an argument `group_keys`, which I gather is supposed to do something relating to how group keys are included in the dataframe subsets. According to the documentation:

> **group_keys** : *boolean, default True*
>
> > When calling apply, add group keys to index to identify pieces

However, I can't really find any examples where `group_keys` makes an actual difference:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 3],
                   [3, 1, 1],
                   [3, 0, 0],
                   [2, 3, 3],
                   [2, 1, 0]], columns=list('xyz'))

gby = df.groupby('x')
gby_k = df.groupby('x', group_keys=False)
```

It doesn't make a difference in the output of `apply`:

```
ap = gby.apply(pd.DataFrame.sum)
#    x  y  z
# x         
# 0  0  1  3
# 2  4  4  3
# 3  6  1  1

ap_k = gby_k.apply(pd.DataFrame.sum)
#    x  y  z
# x         
# 0  0  1  3
# 2  4  4  3
# 3  6  1  1
```

And even if you print out the grouped subsets as you go, the results are still identical:

```
def printer_func(x):
    print(x)
    return x

print('gby')
print('--------------')
gby.apply(printer_func)
print('--------------')

print('gby_k')
print('--------------')
gby_k.apply(printer_func)
print('--------------')

# gby
# --------------
#    x  y  z
# 0  0  1  3
#    x  y  z
# 0  0  1  3
#    x  y  z
# 3  2  3  3
# 4  2  1  0
#    x  y  z
# 1  3  1  1
# 2  3  0  0
# --------------
# gby_k
# --------------
#    x  y  z
# 0  0  1  3
#    x  y  z
# 0  0  1  3
#    x  y  z
# 3  2  3  3
# 4  2  1  0
#    x  y  z
# 1  3  1  1
# 2  3  0  0
# --------------
```

I considered the possibility that the default argument is actually `True`, but switching `group_keys` to explicitly `False` doesn't make a difference either.  What exactly is this argument for?

(Run on `pandas` version `0.18.1`)

**Edit:**
I did find a way where `group_keys` changes behavior, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34282449/467366):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

row_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(((0, 1), (2, 3, 4)))
d = pd.DataFrame([[4, 3], [1, 3], [1, 1], [2, 4], [0, 1], [4, 2]], index=row_idx)

df_n = d.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, [0]))
#        0  1
# 0 0 2  4  3
#     3  1  3
# 1 1 4  4  2
#     2  2  4

df_k = d.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2, [0]))

#      0  1
# 0 2  4  3
#   3  1  3
# 1 4  4  2
#   2  2  4
```

However, I'm still not clear on the intelligible principle behind what `group_keys` is *supposed to do*. This behavior does not seem intuitive based on **@piRSquared**'s answer.

Answer (score 15):

`group_keys` parameter in [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) comes handy during [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) operations that creates an additional index column corresponding to the grouped columns (`group_keys=True`) and eliminates in the case (`group_keys=False`) especially during the case when trying to perform operations on individual columns.

One such instance:

```
In [21]: gby = df.groupby('x',group_keys=True).apply(lambda row: row['x'])

In [22]: gby
Out[22]: 
x   
0  0    0
2  3    2
   4    2
3  1    3
   2    3
Name: x, dtype: int64

In [23]: gby_k = df.groupby('x', group_keys=False).apply(lambda row: row['x'])

In [24]: gby_k
Out[24]: 
0    0
3    2
4    2
1    3
2    3
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

One of its intended applications could be to group by one of the levels of the hierarchy by converting it to a `Multi-index` dataframe object.

```
In [27]: gby.groupby(level='x').sum()
Out[27]: 
x
0    0
2    4
3    6
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I still feel like I don't have a sense of what `group_key` is intending here. Like... why does it have this specific behavior, **only** when you have grouped columns? Seems like it only creates a multi-index when the `apply` function returns a `Series`, but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 7):

If you are passing a function that preserves an index, pandas tries to keep that information.  But if you pass a function that removes all semblance of index information, `group_keys=True` allows you to keep that information.

Use this instead

```
f = lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then the different `groupby`

```
gby.apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

[image]

```
gby_k.apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Is this the full extent of what `group_keys` does? I've edited the question with another example of where `group_keys` does something, but it does not seem consistent with the meaning of `group_keys` you've articulated here.

Answer (score 1):

It confused me as well. Here are some "notes to self" that might help others.

The only `group_keys` difference is in the *output* of `apply` (if it is so-called 'transform-like', that is).

The input to the passed function does *not* change: its index always includes the group keys! One can `.reset_index(group_key_levels_to_drop, drop=True)` if needed.

By default, currently (as of pandas version 1.5.3) group keys are *not* prepended to the index of DataFrame *results*. In the future they will be (as already happens for Series results). Due to this upcoming change in default behavior, not specifying an explicit `group_keys=` for DataFrame results currently [shows](https://mkleinbort.medium.com/the-new-pandas-groupby-explained-c3c65867e1cd) a `FutureWarning`:

> Not prepending group keys to the result index of transform-like apply. ...

Aside: if `group_keys=True` (or by default for Series results), also including `as_index=False` causes the prepended index to be group index *numbers* (0, 1, ...). Apart from backwards compatibility with versions that had this behavior by default, I cannot think of any reason to do that. The same holds for the obsolete `squeeze=True` to convert a one-column DataFrame result into a Series.

Answer (score 0):

Such a convoluted documentation. Answer is simple (applicable only for `groupby`, followed by `apply`):

***Condition1***
***When the result set length is same as the original df***

1. a) If the result set is ordered by the group, `group_keys=True` will add the group key.
   Example: `df.groupby(...).apply(lambda df: df[0] + df[1])` ***# results are ordered by their specific group***
   b) If the result set is ordered by the original index, then there is no need for the library to specify group key as the original order is still retained.
   Example: `df.groupby(..).apply(lambda df: df + 1)` ***# results are in the original order***

***Condition2***

2. When result set length is not the same as original length, then group key is always included.
   Example: `df.groupby(...).apply(lambda x: x.mean())` ***# results length is changed/reduced, group_keys has no effect***